# Scrollbar on firefox not working

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I put the custom scroll bar it works on all browser but on Firefox it doesn't work.

```
::-moz-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
}


::-moz-scrollbar-track {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0); 
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-moz-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not support custom scrollbars. See more at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790.
You can use [JQuery Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html).